# Angular 2 svg image showing up as blank image

Tags: angular, svg, data-binding

I am trying to display an svg image where the path to the image is being passed down from the parent component. Like so:

Parent HTML:

```
<div class="home__top-right">
        <dashboard-button btnImg="../../../../assets/dashboard/Hex_Cube_White.svg"></dashboard-button>
        <dashboard-button btnImg="../../../../assets/dashboard/Hex_Cube_White.svg"></dashboard-button>
    </div>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-button',
    templateUrl: './dashboard-button.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard-button.component.scss']

})

export class DashboardButtonComponent {

    @Input() btnImg: string;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dash-button__body">
        <img class="dash-button__body-img" [src]="btnImg">
        <p class="dash-button__body-title">{{btnImg}}</p>
    </div>
```

All I can see if the empty img icon and the svg is being downloaded as type text/html instead of svg+xml like all my other svg I'm using. The path is correct because if I place the path directly into the source I can see the image. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: are u on prod mode??

Comment: syntax error it should be `[btnImg]` rather than `btnImg`

Comment: I'm in dev mode